# pam_ldap and ldaps can't contact ldap server

Tags: centos, ldap, authentication, pam

I'm trying to allow authentication via LDAP on a CentOS host system. But I always get a *Can't contact LDAP server* error from pam_ldap.

The LDAP server is pingable and  authentication works perfectly with ldap://, but not with ldaps://. It also works perfectly with ldaps:// on debian OS, but not on CentOS.

I got the *Can't contact* error also with **$ ldapsearch ...** but I fixed it setting *TLS_REQCERT allow* in /etc/openldap/ldap.conf. But setting this for /etc/pam_ldap.conf does not help.

Steps I did:

- *$ yum install pam_ldap nss-pam-ldapd openldap-clients*
- *$ authconfig-tui* and activate LDAP for Authentication
- modify */etc/pam_ldap*
- modify */etc/nslcd.conf*
- modify */etc/openldap/ldap.conf*
- create */etc/ldap/ldap.conf* (read somewhere that it's a fall-back config file path)
- create */etc/ldap.conf* (with same content as /etc/ldap/ldap.conf)
- restart services nscd and nslcd

Some more information:

- the CA-Cert from LDAP-Server is readable for everyone.
- iptables is disabled

Also confusing is the IP in */var/log/secure*. There it says *Failed password for testuser from 10.1.1.1*, but the configured IP for LDAP server is 10.1.1.42 and the host IP is 10.1.1.27. Anyways, if I use the uri ldap://10.1.1.42 and comment the line *ssl on* authentication works like a charm.

Any ideas?

.

Trying to authenticate via pam, **/var/log/secure**

```
Sep 15 09:50:37 client-server unix_chkpwd[16146]: password check failed for user (testuser)
Sep 15 09:50:37 client-server sshd[16144]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=10.1.1.1  user=testuser
Sep 15 09:50:37 client-server sshd[16144]: pam_ldap: ldap_simple_bind Can't contact LDAP server
Sep 15 09:50:37 client-server sshd[16144]: pam_ldap: reconnecting to LDAP server...
Sep 15 09:50:37 client-server sshd[16144]: pam_ldap: ldap_simple_bind Can't contact LDAP server
Sep 15 09:50:40 client-server sshd[16144]: Failed password for testuser from 10.1.1.1 port 11339 ssh2
Sep 15 09:50:40 client-server sshd[16145]: Received disconnect from 10.1.1.1: 13: Unable to authenticate
```

Run **$ ldapsearch -v -H ldaps://10.1.1.42/ -D cn=admin,dc=sub,dc=example,dc=org -W -x -b dc=sub,dc=example,dc=org -d1** to check if ldaps// is working. (Yes, it works)

```
ldap_url_parse_ext(ldaps://10.1.1.42/)
ldap_initialize( ldaps://10.1.1.42:636/??base )
ldap_create
ldap_url_parse_ext(ldaps://10.1.1.42:636/??base)
Enter LDAP Password:
ldap_sasl_bind
ldap_send_initial_request
ldap_new_connection 1 1 0
ldap_int_open_connection
ldap_connect_to_host: TCP 10.1.1.42:636
ldap_new_socket: 3
ldap_prepare_socket: 3
ldap_connect_to_host: Trying 10.1.1.42:636
ldap_pvt_connect: fd: 3 tm: -1 async: 0
TLS: certificate [CN=sub.example.org,OU=test-ou,O=test-o,ST=test-st,C=DE] is not valid - error -8172:Peer's certificate issuer has been marked as not trusted by the user..
TLS certificate verification: subject: CN=sub.example.org,OU=test-ou,O=test-o,ST=test-st,C=DE, issuer: CN=sub.example.org,OU=test-ou,O=test-o,ST=test-st,C=DE, cipher: AES-128, security level: high, secret key bits: 128, total key bits: 128, cache hits: 0, cache misses: 0, cache not reusable: 0
ldap_open_defconn: successful
ldap_send_server_request
...
```

Content of **/etc/pam_ldap.conf**

```
ldap_version 3
pam_password crypt
uri ldaps://10.1.1.42:636
base dc=sub,dc=example,dc=org
ssl on
tls_reqcert allow
tls_cacertfile /srv/ldap-cacert.pem
tls_checkpeer no
```

Content of **/etc/openldap/ldap.conf**

```
TLS_REQCERT allow
TLS_CACERTFILE /srv/ldap-cacert.pem
URI ldaps://10.1.1.42:636/
BASE dc=sub,dc=example,dc=org
```

Content of **/etc/nslcd.conf**

```
uid nslcd
gid ldap
ssl on
tls_reqcert allow
tls_cacertfile /srv/ldap-cacert.pem
uri ldaps://10.1.1.42:636/
base dc=sub,dc=example,dc=org
```

Content of **/etc/ldap.conf** and **/etc/ldap/ldap.conf**:

```
tls_checkpeer no
tls_reqcert allow
tls_cacertfile /srv/ldap-cacert.pem
uri ldaps://10.1.1.42:636/
base dc=sub,dc=example,dc=org
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Migtor pushed me in the right direction. Thank you!

When I removed *TLS_REQCERT* and checked for the *ldapsearch* errors I also got `TLS: error: connect - force handshake failure: errno 2 - moznss error -8172`.

My CA certificate is the correct one, but openldap uses Mozilla Network Security Services (MozNSS) by default for checking the authority. So I have to add my self-signed CA to this database.

**Edit:** As Migtor pointed out in his comment below, this should apply only to CentOS, RHEL and derivatives.

.

## Solution

First copy your CA certificate to the client (my path: /etc/openldap/cacerts/ldap-cacert.pem)

After installing *pam_ldap* a MozNSS database is located in /etc/openldap/certs :

- run `# certutil -d /etc/openldap/certs -A -n "ldap CA" -t TCu,Cu,Tuw -a -i /etc/openldap/cacerts/ldap-cacert.pem`

  - -n "ldap CA" is just a name to identify your certificate in the MozNSS database
- verify: `# certutil -L -d /etc/openldap/certs`

New content of my **/etc/pam_ldap.conf**

```
ldap_version 3
pam_password crypt
uri ldaps://[FQDN-of-my-ldap-server]:636
base dc=sub,dc=example,dc=org
ssl on
tls_cacertdir /etc/openldap/certs
```

.

### What about nss-pam-ldapd ?

This is no longer required. I purged it and /etc/nslcd.conf is no longer available.

.

Sources:

- https://www.dragonsreach.it/2013/03/27/setting-ssl-certificates-openldap-mozilla-nss-database/
- http://www.bradchen.com/blog/2012/08/openldap-tls-issue
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/NSS/tools/NSS_Tools_certutil

Comment: Glad you got it working ;). This should apply only to CentOS, RHEL and derivatives, I believe most distros compile openldap with openssl, not with nss. Anyway, it's strange that using a correct `TLS_CACERTFILE` didn't work, maybe that it's just openssl specific.

Answer (score 6):

The clue is in the `ldapsearch` command output:

```
TLS: certificate [CN=sub.example.org,OU=test-ou,O=test-o,ST=test-st,C=DE] is not valid - error -8172:Peer's certificate issuer has been marked as not trusted by the user..
TLS certificate verification: subject: CN=sub.example.org,OU=test-ou,O=test-o,ST=test-st,C=DE, issuer: CN=sub.example.org,OU=test-ou,O=test-o,ST=test-st,C=DE, cipher: AES-128, security level: high, secret key bits: 128, total key bits: 128, cache hits: 0, cache misses: 0, cache not reusable: 0
```

It says: `certificate ... is not valid... Peer's certificate issuer has been marked as not trusted by the user`. That means the CA used to issue the server certificate is not trusted. It seems to me that the CACERTFILE `TLS_CACERTFILE /srv/ldap-cacert.pem` does not contain the right CA certificate. It won't work until you get an error clean `ldapsearch` output.

Once that is solved you may get errors due to the CN of the certificate. If you do, try using `ldaps://sub.example.org/` as URI instead of `ldaps://10.1.1.42/`. If your DNS doesn't resolve that name, just put it in your `/etc/hosts` file (just for testing, you should update your DNS records).